# pyinstaller exe freezes when using "from PyQt5 import uic"

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, photoshop

I am trying to use python to launch Adobe photoshop and run a script inside photoshop.
Below is my code. It works when I run from the windows command line using python 3.9.1 
If I use pyinstaller to make an exe using `pyinstaller Photoshop.py` ,then run the created .exe. Photoshop is started and script begins to run and then the process freezes. 
If I comment out the second line in the below code `# from PyQt5 import uic` then run pyinstaller again the resulting .exe that is created has no problems and runs as if I ran it using python from the command line. 

Any ideas why importing uic from PyQt5 would mess up pyinstaller in some way?


I realize im importing UIC and not using it. This problem is part of a larger project where the module is used. I have just created a small example here to get help with my problem.

```
import subprocess
from PyQt5 import uic

class Photoshop2021:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Created")

    def runBenchmark(self):
        cmd = [r"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2021\Photoshop.exe",
               r"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2021\Presets\Scripts\TCL Photoshop Benchmark_AUTO 2.3.jsxbin"]

        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

Photoshop2021().runBenchmark()
```

Here is the output of pyinstaller when the import statement is uncommented and the photoshop process freezes.

```
C:\Users\Z8G4\Desktop\Automation-Sidekick\build\Temp>pyinstaller --noconfirm PhotoshopTest.py
55 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.4
55 INFO: Python: 3.9.1
58 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
61 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Z8G4\Desktop\Automation-Sidekick\build\Temp\PhotoshopTest.spec
64 INFO: UPX is not available.
66 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Z8G4\\Desktop\\Automation-Sidekick\\build\\Temp',
 'C:\\Users\\Z8G4\\Desktop\\Automation-Sidekick\\build\\Temp']
73 INFO: checking Analysis
74 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
74 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
79 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
87 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
90 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2083 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
2084 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib'
3632 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3783 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3785 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\z8g4\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
3840 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\z8g4\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
3857 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Z8G4\Desktop\Automation-Sidekick\build\Temp\PhotoshopTest.py
3925 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook PyQt5.uic.port_v2 from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-PyQt5.uic.port_v2.py'.
3989 INFO: Processing module hooks...
3990 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3993 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3995 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3996 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4075 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4076 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4110 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4111 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4113 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4268 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
4269 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4332 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4457 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4719 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.uic.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4723 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4724 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4725 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4764 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4872 INFO: checking Tree
4872 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
4874 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
4924 INFO: checking Tree
4925 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
4926 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
4996 INFO: checking Tree
4997 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
4999 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
5019 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
5033 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
5035 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
5037 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
5044 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
5045 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
5052 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
5938 INFO: Looking for eggs
5938 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\z8g4\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
5940 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
5946 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Z8G4\Desktop\Automation-Sidekick\build\Temp\build\PhotoshopTest\warn-PhotoshopTest.txt
5983 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Z8G4\Desktop\Automation-Sidekick\build\Temp\build\PhotoshopTest\xref-PhotoshopTest.html
5994 INFO: checking PYZ
5994 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
5995 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Z8G4\Desktop\Automation-Sidekick\build\Temp\build\PhotoshopTest\PYZ-00.pyz
6449 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Z8G4\Desktop\Automation-Sidekick\build\Temp\build\PhotoshopTest\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
6460 INFO: checking PKG
6460 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
6461 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
6478 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
6479 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\z8g4\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
6479 INFO: checking EXE
6480 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
6483 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
6485 INFO: Copying icons from ['c:\\users\\z8g4\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
6486 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
6486 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
6487 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
6487 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
6490 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
6491 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
6495 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
6498 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
6501 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Z8G4\Desktop\Automation-Sidekick\build\Temp\build\PhotoshopTest\PhotoshopTest.exe
6830 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
6833 INFO: checking COLLECT
6833 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
6835 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
7267 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: If you run your EXE from a command prompt/terminal, do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: No, I get "Created" b/c that is printed in the constructor. but no errors or warnings
[CMD+Frozen IMG](https://imgur.com/a/Hghf2DA)

Comment: I ran your code, but replaced Photoshop with Notepad. Notepad runs normally. Makes me wonder if something about the argument you are passing to Photoshop is where it messes up. Does the EXE with `import uic` mess up if you run it without the extra script argument? Or maybe the script argument needs to be enclosed in quotes because of the spaces (e.g. `'"C:\Program...Scripts..."'. Or if you get really desperate replace the script argument with the 8dot3 version (C:\PROGRA~1\...) so that there are no spaces.

Comment: I did some more testing and it looks like Photoshop version 22.4.3 is working with the above script but then Photoshop version 22.5 and 22.5.1 dont work. Could there be something going on with the context where pyinstaller runs the process that photoshop doesnt like?